# Correct way to handle entities anytime in middle of conversation

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have started working with the LUIS and bot framework recently, after having some experience also with API AI / Google home development.

In the sample below that, I will use an example (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-waterfall) is exemplified a step by step interaction with a user. First, it asks for a date, then a number, then a name for the reserve, and so on.

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
function (session) {
    session.send("Welcome to the dinner reservation.");
    builder.Prompts.time(session, "Please provide a reservation date and time (e.g.: June 6th at 5pm)");
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.reservationDate = builder.EntityRecognizer.resolveTime([results.response]);
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "How many people are in your party?");
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.partySize = results.response;
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "Who's name will this reservation be under?");
},
function (session, results) {
    session.dialogData.reservationName = results.response;

    // Process request and display reservation details
    session.send("Reservation confirmed. Reservation details: <br/>Date/Time: %s <br/>Party size: %s <br/>Reservation name: %s",
        session.dialogData.reservationDate, session.dialogData.partySize, session.dialogData.reservationName);
    session.endDialog();
}]);
```

In my code, I have a similar multi-parameter dialog, but I want to allow the user to answer with multiple information at the same time in any of the responses it have. For example, after providing the reservation date the user can say "a reserve for Robert for 10 people", so both numbers of people and reservation name are giving at the same time.

To identify these text entities I suppose I have to call LUIS and get the entities resolved from the session context. I notice that the bot object has a recognized method that I think can work for that.

My question is how do I organize the structure of the code and the LUIS utterances and entities? Right now I have an intent with some entities and several utterances samples, but if I send this 'partial' user sentence I think it will not be mapped to the same intent and may not identify the entities with a small sentence like that.

How should I handle this? Do I need to provide samples for the intent with these partial sentences, that may contain only some of the entities?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should provide samples for all those utterances that you want to your intent to recognize. Not a million of samples, but just as few to get everything trained.

Then, the other problem that you might want to solve next, is asking for the information for those entities missing in the utterance. You can do that manually or you could go one step further and explore the [LUIS Action Binding](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/blog-LUISActionBinding) library.